# Eclipse CDT C/C++ Error

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I'm testing out the CDT package for eclipse. I am trying to compile and run a simple Hello World program in C.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void {
    printf("Hello World");

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
   }
```

But it's giving me the error: unresolved inclusion: 
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your exact context (OS, Eclipse version, CDT version).
It can be:

- an [index issue](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg16571.html),

> > Just recently upgraded to Eclipse Ganymede RC4 with CDT 5 (release from June 17th). I am having some difficulties with "Unresolved Inclusion" warnings (from the Indexer I assume?).
>
> I had the same problem the first time I built my project after changing from Callisto to Ganymede. I changed from the Fast Indexer to the Full Indexer and did a full index, which resolved the problem (I also checked Index All Files, but I don't know if that was essential). I could then change back to the Fast Indexer and everything worked.

- a [preference issue](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg12849.html):

> I guess this could be solved in the preferences for the project.
> Under the point `c/c++ general -> Paths and symbols`. In the tab "`includes`" under `GNU C++`, you can add the location of the include files.

- or, as [this thread illustrates](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg16485.html), a context issue:

> This happens if you use Eclipse/CDT on a windows system with Cygwin or mingw.
> When CDT follows the include paths  there in no path "`asm`" in the include directory - just an "`asm.lnk`" which causes the problem.

Comment: for the second solution, a preference issue: where would the location of the include files be?

Comment: @Krysten: it was about specific include files not in standard place, hence this procedure.

Comment: @kachilous: I suppose that depends on the system. On OS X, pointing it at /usr/include fixed a lot of these "inclusion" errors for me.